# How to get nodes, connected to the edge is being deleted?

Tags: vis.js-network

**What do I have**: graph network with edges.

**What do I want**: I want to know, which nodes were connected to the certain edge I just deleted.

**My code**:

```js
var nodes = new vis.DataSet([{
    id: 1,
    label: 'Node 1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: 'Node 2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    label: 'Node 3'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    label: 'Node 4'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    label: 'Node 5'
  }
])
// create an array with edges
var edges = new vis.DataSet([{
    from: 1,
    to: 3
  },
  {
    from: 1,
    to: 2
  },
  {
    from: 2,
    to: 4
  },
  {
    from: 2,
    to: 5
  },
  {
    from: 3,
    to: 3
  }
])
// create a network
var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork')
var data = {
  nodes: nodes,
  edges: edges
};
var options = {
  interaction: {
    hover: true
  },
  manipulation: {
    enabled: true,
    deleteEdge: function(edge, callback) {
      callback(edge)
      console.log(edge)
    }
  }
}
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options)
network.on("click", function(params) {
  params.event = "[original event]"
  document.getElementById('eventSpan').innerHTML = '<h2>Click event:</h2>' + JSON.stringify(params, null, 4)
  console.log('click event, getNodeAt returns: ' + this.getNodeAt(params.pointer.DOM))
})
```

```css
<style>#mynetwork {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

</style>
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vis-network@latest/dist/vis-network.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vis-network@latest/dist/vis-network.min.js"></script>
<div id="mynetwork"></div>
<pre id="eventSpan"></pre>
```

**Steps to reproduce**:

1. Click "Edit"
2. Click on any edge, connected with two different nodes
3. Click "Delete selected"

**Problem**: `edge` object in `console.log(edge)` contains `Nodes` `array`, but it's empty. I expect it might contain array of two `Nodes`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't contain nodes because no nodes were deleted. After you deleted the edge the information is lost so you have to do it before you delete it. There is `network.getConnectedNodes(edgeId)` method for this.